# How to get started with vSphere 6.0 and set up the web client?

Tags: server, vmware, vsphere

*Linked from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/729925/how-to-get-started-with-vsphere-and-set-up-the-web-client)*

I've been tasked with setting up some VMs. I've been given some admin details but no further guidance. The server is a fresh install.

My problem is that I'm on Linux/OSX and don't want to run Windows aside from setting up after which I hope to be able to manage things through the web client.

I think there is an ESXi installation. This would be Version 6. How do I set up the web client?

I've installed vSphere Client on a local Windows VM.. not sure what to do with it though.

The documentation is pretty awful and there hasn't been much useful info on the net. I'm really stuck as I didn't set these up and haven't used servers like this before, so I have no context or understanding of the VMWare ecosystem beyond using a virtual machine locally! (even then I've preferred Virtualbox)

Any advice would be amazing

p.s accessing https://[ipaddress]/vsphere-client does not work. Produces a blank browser page... with no html served as an error

Answer (score 2):

If you have the name of the server on which the VMs are stored, type this into the URL of a web browser then it gives you management options or alternatively use this login screen: [image]